# Download audio fragment with XHR

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, web-audio-api

I would like to download fragments of large audio files and post-process them for audio visualization (using Webaudio API). I would like to use XHR to download these fragments.

Let us take https://traffic.megaphone.fm/MERE7176906291.mp3?updated=1632752564 as an example. Let us say, I want to fetch fragment `#t=300,330` (half a minute fragment starting at `5:00`). I would need to set header `Range: range_from-range_to` in XHR request. How do I go about calculating the byte offset start and end?

Looking at `ffprobe` output to get sample and bit rate:

```sh
$ ffprobe MERE7176906291.mp3\?updated\=1632752564 
ffprobe version 4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Ubuntu 10.2.1-20ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[mp3 @ 0x559e92dc3b40] Skipping 1 bytes of junk at 38361.
[mp3 @ 0x559e92dc3b40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'MERE7176906291.mp3?updated=1632752564':
  Metadata:
    title           :  Miranda Kerr on Motherhood, Her Modern Family, and Why She Proudly Calls Herself a “Turtle”
    lyrics-ENG      : <p>Model and Kora Organics founder Miranda Kerr dishes on the art of a cheeky wink, her award-winning skincare line, and how she fell in love with Katy Perry.</p>
    album           : Ladies First with Laura Brown
    genre           : Podcast
    date            : 2020
  Duration: 00:35:04.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x500 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      title           : image
      comment         : Other
```

For e.g., I seeked to timestamp `7:40` in my browser and I a request in network tab of dev tools with header `Range: bytes=4816896-`. In the response, I see a header `Content-Range: bytes 4816896-33713332/33713333`.

I have a few questions:

1. How do I calculate the byte offset?
2. Is it dependent upon audio format since mp3, flac, etc. formats compress the data?

Comment: Yes, it is dependent on the audio format. For OGG format, you would need to download the header (first bytes of the file), decode keyframe indices, convert to timesteps, and multiply to get the byte offset. I don't know much about other formats. I would recommend a different approach, unless you plan to do this as a long research project.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelG. Obviously, the browser is able to do this, is there not any open source library with wide range of support for various audio formats to do so? After all, browsers like Chromium are open-source.

I tried downloading the fragment with `fetch` API with `#t=start,end` fragment, but no avail. It downloads the entire mp3 file.

Comment: [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/media-fragments) is limited to video at the moment, so it won't work for mp3, unfortunately. Implementing this is difficult, even for the engineering teams at Google and Mozilla. I'm not sure an open source library would be allowed to decode a proprietary format, but if you can find one, it might be possible to compile to WASM and import it into your JS project.

Comment: Hey @MichaelG, can you please clarify on support being restricted to video only? Obviously, I am able to seek to random audio locations in browser (FF, Chrome, Edge) for a variety of formats. That is, the media fragment support for audio seems to exists in all the modern browsers. So, can you please clarify why you said the support being restricted to video only?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a note from caniuse: "Only appears to support the #t=n,n control for selecting a range of video, and possibly track=(name) & id=(name) (not yet tested)". Please note that you specifically asked about calculating byte offsets, not about using the media-fragments API. I won't post an answer because I can't help you calculate byte offsets, but please don't be surprised if no one else does either. (It is very hard.) Probably better to reword your question rather than continue these long comments.